# C# WPF Focus previous textBox if current erased

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I've a project where I need to focus previous field if current one is empty but user keep deleting. Like when you type CD-Key somewhere. You have couple blocks with 4-5 symbols each. And if you erase 3rd textBox for example you will be forced back to the second textBox right after 3rd one become emprty.

```
if (textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
{
     Keyboard.Focus(textBox1);
}
```

This code works fine but considering that I've another onfocus event so textBox2 become empty as soon as got focus and due to code above focus forcing back to the textBox1. So it's looped.

If I get it right I need to catch pressing the Delete button, right? But here is my problem goes. I don't know how to insert this code

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
        {
             Keyboard.Focus(textBox1);
        }
    }
}
```

inside this function:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (textBox2.Text.Length == 2)
     {
          Keyboard.Focus(textBox3);
     }
     // HERE I NEED SOMETHING LIKE ELSE IF (e.Key == Key.Delete) {...
}
```

Help me please.
UPD. I've tried one more solution but it doesn't work:

```
private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
     {
          if (textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
          {
               Keyboard.Focus(textBox1);
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the generic soution for arbitrary amount of TextBox'es.

The initialization of the TextBox'es list:

```
private readonly List<TextBox> _textBoxes;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { _textBox1, _textBox2, _textBox3 };
}
```

The version with KeyUp event:

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
        return;

    var current = (TextBox)sender;
    if (current.Text.Any())
        return;

    var index = _textBoxes.IndexOf(current);
    if (index == 0)
        return;

    var previous = _textBoxes[index - 1];
    previous.Focus();
    previous.CaretIndex = previous.Text.Length;
}
```

The above version dissalows to jump through TextBox'es in press and hold scenario. To get around this, use TextChanged event:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var current = (TextBox)sender;
    if (current.Text.Any())
        return;

    var index = _textBoxes.IndexOf(current);
    if (index == 0)
        return;

    var previous = _textBoxes[index - 1];
    previous.Focus();
    previous.CaretIndex = previous.Text.Length;
}
```

Third solution with PreviewKeyDown that supports only Key.Delete:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.Delete)
        return;

    var current = (TextBox)sender;
    if (current.Text.Length != 0)
        return;

    var index = _textBoxes.IndexOf(current);
    if (index == 0)
        return;

    var previous = _textBoxes[index - 1];
    previous.Focus();
    previous.CaretIndex = 0;
}
```

Fourth solution also with PreviewKeyDown that supports both Key.Delete and Key.Back:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.Delete && e.Key != Key.Back)
        return;

    var current = (TextBox)sender;
    if (current.Text.Length != 0)
        return;

    var index = _textBoxes.IndexOf(current);
    if (index == 0)
        return;

    var previous = _textBoxes[index - 1];
    previous.Focus();

    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        previous.CaretIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: new List<TextBox>(new[] { _textBox1, _textBox2, _textBox3 }); I'm not sure we need underscropes here. Generally your solution works, but I'm not clear about the second part. And why can't if be done via KeyDown event? So we won't need any TextChanged fixes at all. Do you have any ideas how to make code provided in my answer work with KeyDown? Let me know please.

Comment: @Mike Key.Delete and Key.Back are not sent to KeyDown event handler but you can use PreviewKeyDown.

Comment: @Mike I believe that maintaining a list of text boxes is more extensible, flexible, maintanable and have less logic repetitions than making a handler for each text box.

Comment: Thank you! It's hard to understand each thing that you have used here, but it works and I hope one day it will become completely clear for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally. This one works:

```
private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
     {
          if (textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
          {
          Keyboard.Focus(textBox1);
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested but should also work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void textBox3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox3.Text == "")
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }                  
}
```